# Laravel super/root controller?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

Is in laravel possible to create a super controller that can share his result with all other controllers? Like id's... I needed it to share a "board id", because inside of that I have some actions where this information is globaly needed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can share data with each controllers, by just extending a `BaseController` like this:

**BaseController.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class BaseController extends Controller
{
    public $yourVariable = 'some_data';
}
```

**UserController.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\User;
use App\Http\Controllers\BaseController;

class UserController extends BaseController
{
    public function show($id)
    {
        // Do your stuff here (use BaseController's common variables here)
        $var = $this->yourVariable;
    }
}
```

Hope this helps!